# Compass function inline-image marked as "unknown" in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, compass-sass

I am using compass to compile SCSS files to css outside of PhpStorm. I find using a command line "compass watch directory" works faster and more efficiently than the PhpStorm file Watcher.

I do have the compass library loaded and the file watcher enabled but the triggers disabled. Despite all this PhpStorm constantly flags the compass function "inline-image" as unknown. The IDE knows I am using compass, it knows I am using SCSS what do I have to do to get it to recognize this as a valid function?

Example:

```
// inline-image is a compass function but is flagged.
background: transparent center center no-repeat inline-image('../images/icons/drag_crosshair.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and a feature request has been created to fix this in Jetbrains products.

Please vote for [WEB-40687](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40687) to be notified on any progress with it.